# Android appcompat dialog with style

Tags: android, dialog, android-appcompat, android-styles

I've created a Dialog using below code in android.

```
final CharSequence[] ss = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
builder.setTitle("title");
builder.setItems(ss, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

    }
});
builder.show();
```

This is MyAlertDialogStyle.xml.

```
<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
</style>
```

There are no effects when pressing items in a dialog. What should I do to change background colors of dialog when pressed in xml file?

Additionally, is there any way to know the list of items that I can modify in xml file?(e.g. colorAccent, backgound, textColorPrimary ...)

Answer (score 0):

You could try with MaterialDialogs library. It's easy to use and you could get the callbacks from buttons / radio / etc even if it's with a custom view.

(link : https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/)

Answer (score 0):

Try next code:

```
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/DialogStyle</item>
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/DialogStyle</item>
    </style>

        <style name="DialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/DialogTitleStyle</item>
        <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/text_color</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearanceButton">@style/DialogWindowTextButton</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

       <!--Colors and Styles-->
    <color name="bar">#FF5722</color>
    <color name="status_bar">#E64A19</color>
    ...
    ...
```